# I have tried to click the button using all techniques. But I am unable to click it

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, css-selectors

```
<button class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" 
        type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="hide()">   
    <i class="fa fa-remove ng-scope"></i>   
</button>
```

**StepDefinition Code:**

```
@And("^Check whether the Alert message display properly$")
public void alert_msg_display() throws Throwable {
    WebElement x= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-hover='LOGIN NOW']")); // Path of login button
    actionClick(driver, x); // To click login button
    WebElement y= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='md-dialog-content ng-binding']")); // Path of Alert message text
    String a = y.getText(); 
    WebElement z= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-remove ng-scope']")); // Path of close button of alert popup
    waitClick(driver, z); // To wait until close button display
    actionClick(driver, z); // Click on close (Note:This operation get FAILED)
    String a1 = "Please Enter Branch Id";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='Branchid']")).sendKeys("HO");
    actionClick(driver, x);
    String b = y.getText();
    waitClick(driver, z);
    actionClick(driver, z);;    
    String b1 = "Please Enter Username (Email Id)";
   if (a.equals(a1) && b.equals(b1))
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case ID: LOG_006 to LOG_010 - Pass");
    else
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case ID: LOG_006 to LOG_010 - Fail");
}
```

**Runner File**

```
public void actionClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement a) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(a).click().build().perform();
}
public void waitClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement a) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(a));
}
```

[image: Alert Popup Screenshot]

I have tried to click the button using `.click` method, `Actions` method, `JSExecutor` method and also used `Wait`... But I am unable to click the button. Please, drop your valuable comments. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Code trials please.

Comment: @DebanjanB check the edited post....

Comment: @SnowGift try to wait until the alert is present                                                         `wait = WebDriverWait(current_user_driver, 5)`                                                                       `wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())` and then                                                            `alert = driver.switch_to.alert` and accept alert `alert.accept()`

Comment: @ManaliKagathara When I am using driver.switchTo().alert(); it shows an error as 'No such alert'

Comment: @SnowGift you can remove alert by press enter key try this in your normal browser is it goes or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should operate on pressing the ESCAPE keys. Please try below:
The following 2 ways could work:

Getting the element locator of that image -> Send Escape to the element.

WebElement loginimg = driver.findElement(By.id("AlertX")); loginimg.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

Or

You can press Escape key by Java Robot class as below:

import java.awt.Robot; import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Robot r = new Robot(); r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: Tnq fr ur Solution... @Kalaiselvan

Comment: Welcome always :)

Answer (score 1):

from my observations, it is clear that it is not an normal browser alert (if it is, then we can't inspect the elements in it) , so the selenium alert related codes won't work here (like driver.switchToAlert() will throw an No such alert).

Try to click using the following code snippet, it may works

```
WebElement z= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", z);
```

Comment: **When I tried to click using JS Executor it shows the following exception:** _org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document_

Comment: did you inspected the element //button[@class='md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple'] with chropath/any other tools ? if it shows element found, then you may need to use explicit wait for elementToBeStale()

Comment: Okay... @Riswan chatholi